# Why would I need SSL on my static ecommerce web page if checkout button activates Gumroad's HTTPS overlay?

Tags: security, ssl, e-commerce

I have a simple, static website selling print and digital books, using Gumroad for purchases.

I'd like to use their overlay, rather than open a new Gumroad page when the "Buy" button is clicked, but they ask for my site to be HTTPS.

Per Gumroad's instructions (https://help.gumroad.com/customer/portal/articles/1622004-how-do-i-set-up-the-gumroad-overlay-), the overlay uses HTTPS, as follows:

> 3. Insert code In your HTML header, enter the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
> src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"> </script>
```

> 4. Drop Your Buttons Now that you've put the overlay script into your page, any time you link to a Gumroad product the overlay will
>      activate. To add the Gumroad Buy Button, put the following code
>      wherever you want to link to your product:

```
​<a href="https://gum.co/XXXX" class="gumroad-button">Buy my
> product</a>
```

> ​Instead of XXXX, you need to insert your product's ID.

If everything from Gumroad, where customers will be entering information that needs to be secure, is HTTPS, why does it matter if my site is HTTPS? What are the risks if it isn't?

Comment: @Cygnus1 Thank you - tried to upvote your reply, but StackOverflow kept marking it as flagged (which I undid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without https somebody may create a fake site mimicking yours. He can do something like

```
<a href="https://gum.co/YYYY" class="gumroad-button">Buy XXXX</a>
```

With HTTPS on your side, he would have to fake your certificate as well - which is much harder.

Lack of HTTPS is not that big of an issue when there is an additional page produced by Gumroad (the one with additional "pay" button) - because at that page, your customer can actually verify that he is buying XXXX and not YYYY.